# Effects of very large functions in C Program?

Tags: c

Ignoring modularity and readability, what are the effects of having large functions in terms of performance against many sub divided functions? (C Language in general).

Comment: The obvious is that you don't have to call lots of functions if you only have one large function. However, on a modern multi-GHz CPU and modern compilers, the cost of calling functions is often negligible. If it will be that for you, I don't know. The only way to know for sure, is for you to measure it.

Comment: I would be incredibly surprised if there was any measurable difference.

Comment: It could depend in part on the structure of the big subroutine.  If it is linear code (few conditions, no loops), then there's little difference.  If there are loops within loops and conditions and so on, you might get better locality of reference (and hence more cache hits) for the code with small subroutines.  Put it like this, the performance benefit of a large function is probably outweighed by the loss of comprehensibility.  And with aggressive inlining and functions declared static, you may well find that your small subroutines are inline in the big function anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Large function probably has a small performance gain over many small functions due to less function calls. But my general rule is: let the compiler deal with optimizations and concentrate on functionality and security.

Comment: Function call overhead is usually eliminated by inlining and dynamic branch prediction.

Answer (score 2):

Functions are an important part of code organization in any programming language. Although, performance wise, having a single large function would decrease the use of the function calls and hence fewer stack jumps and leading to a better performing code. But, not every project has the luxury of not being modular and having code that's unreadable or worse confusing or misleading. Over time, the cost of the project with large functions will be far greater than a project with small functions, in terms of maintenance, refactoring, feature enhancements,etc.Again, a function is big only when analyzed in a certain context and there can be some situations where a big function could not be broken down into smaller pieces and its totally acceptable, as long as it is well-designed and simple.

Remember the first rule of writing a function: `do one thing and one thing well`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and it's not on-topic for this site.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: agreed its off-topic. But, I just wanted to help and anyways marked it as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

In C programming For Each Function Call a Stack Frame is Created So in case of single function there will be only one stack and there is no need of stack jump but in case of many sub divided functions, each functions will be having a separate stack and for each function call there will be stack jump so the performance may be reduced depending upon the compiler optimization.